# Latex Error: \begin{list} on input line 130 ended by /end{document}

Tags: spacing, errors, resume, bullets

Found a Latex resume online that is supposed to work, but there is some unknown error that I am getting. I believe the formatting is correct, but I am not positive because I do not know latex well.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{breaklinks=true,%
pagecolor=white,%
colorlinks=true,%
linkcolor=cyan,%
urlcolor=MyDarkBlue}

\definecolor{MyDarkBlue}{rgb}{0,0.0,0.45}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Formatting parameters  %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newlength{\tabin}
\setlength{\tabin}{1em}
\newlength{\secsep}
\setlength{\secsep}{0.1cm}

\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\setlength{\parskip}{0in}
\setlength{\itemsep}{0in}
\setlength{\topsep}{0in}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}

\definecolor{contactgray}{gray}{0.3}
\pagestyle{empty}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%  Template Definitions  %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\lineunder}{\vspace*{-8pt} \\ \hspace*{-6pt} \hrulefill \\ \vspace*{-15pt}}
\newcommand{\name}[1]{\begin{center}\textsc{\Huge#1}\\\end{center}}
\newcommand{\program}[1]{\begin{center}\textsc{#1}\end{center}}
\newcommand{\contact}[1]{\begin{center}\color{contactgray}{\small#1}\end{center}}

\newenvironment{tabbedsection}[1]{
  \begin{list}{}{
      \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
      \setlength{\labelsep}{0pt}
      \setlength{\labelwidth}{0pt}
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\tabin}
      \setlength{\rightmargin}{\tabin}
      \setlength{\listparindent}{0pt}
      \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
      \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
      \setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}
      \setlength{\topsep}{#1}
    }
  \item[]
}{\end{list}}

\newenvironment{nospacetabbing}{
    \begin{tabbing}
}{\end{tabbing}\vspace{-1.2em}}

\newenvironment{resume_header}{}{\vspace{0pt}}


\newenvironment{resume_section}[1]{
  \filbreak
  \vspace{2\secsep}
  \textsc{\large#1}
  \lineunder
  \begin{tabbedsection}{\secsep}
}{\end{tabbedsection}}

\newenvironment{resume_subsection}[2][]{
  \textbf{#2} \hfill {\footnotesize #1} \hspace{2em}
  \begin{tabbedsection}{0.5\secsep}
}{\end{tabbedsection}}

\newenvironment{subitems}{
  \renewcommand{\labelitemi}{-}
  \begin{itemize}
      \setlength{\labelsep}{1em}
}{\end{itemize}}

\newenvironment{resume_employer}[4]{
  \vspace{\secsep}
  \textbf{#1} \\ 
  \indent {\small #2} \hfill {\footnotesize#3 (#4)}
  \begin{tabbedsection}{0pt}
  \begin{subitems}
}{\end{subitems}\end{tabbedsection}}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     Start Document     %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{resume_header}
\name{Joma}
\program{2A Honours Mathematics -- Computer Science Major}
\contact{joma@joma.io \hspace{2cm} 345-234-3245 \hspace{2cm}Student ID: 00000000}
\end{resume_header}

\begin{resume_section}{About Me}
  \begin{nospacetabbing}

  \textbf{Technical Skills}  \= C/C++, Python, Java, Unix/Linux, Excel VBA, MySQL, Scheme, \LaTeX\\*
  \textbf{Languages} \> Fluent in French; Conversational Proficiency in Cantonese\\*
  \textbf{Art Technology} \> Adobe Photoshop, Adobe Premiere Pro, Illustrator\\*
  \textbf{Interests} \> Digital Art, Cinematography, Photography, Design, Poker\\*
  \end{nospacetabbing}

\end{resume_section}

\begin{resume_section}{Work Experience}
  \begin{resume_employer}{Statistics Canada}{Enumerator, Census 2011}{Montreal, QC}{Summer 2011}
    \item Helped and convinced respondents in their dwellings to fill in the census forms
    \item Fixed discrepancies in respondents answers to prevent anomalies in the 2011 Census
    \item Managed and sorted census report in Statistics Canada's online database
  \end{resume_employer}
  
  \begin{resume_employer}{McDonald’s, Aramark Canada, Compass Group}{Cashier, Food Services}{Montreal/Waterloo, QC/ON}{June 2009 - April 2013}
    \item Worked in various food services company as a part time job during studies
    \item Provided excellent customer service while executing quick transactions with accuracy in a stressful and fast paced environment
    \item Maintained a sanitary workplace abiding to Canada's Food and Drugs Act and Regulations
  \end{resume_employer}
\end{resume_section}


\begin{resume_section}{Competitions and Personal Projects}
  \begin{resume_subsection}[(Feburary 2013)]{Rotman International Trading Competition}
  \begin{subitems}
    \item Developed quantitative strategies and applied them during the competition againts undergraduate and graduate students from schools around the world
    \item Implemented Excel VBA macros to facilitate trading and to datamine the simulated cases for research
    \item Wrote a bot for the Algo Case in VBA using their RIT client API that optimizes asset liquidation and profit from arbitrage
    \end{subitems}
  \end{resume_subsection}


  \begin{resume_subsection}[(March 2013)]{Prism Trading Competition}
  \begin{subitems}
    \item Competed in the simulated Sales and Trading Case using the RIT software winning first place (1/12)
    \item Calculated profitability of large offers using VWAP while market making.
    \item Provided liquidity to the market, to profit from competitors large market orders.
    \end{subitems}
  \end{resume_subsection}



  \begin{resume_subsection}[(December 2012)]{Intrade}
    \begin{subitems}
        \item Wrote an algorithm in Python to trade DOW contracts using Black-Scholes binary option pricing.
        \item Automated trades using the Intrade API which required the use of XML processing using ETree libraries
        \item Data mined live feed from various websites for live Index Pricing and Volatility by parsing HTML
    \end{subitems}
  \end{resume_subsection}
  
  \begin{resume_subsection}[(December 2011 - January 2012)]{Poker}
    \begin{subitems}
    \item Simultaneously played 24 cash game tables with 0.01\$/0.02\$ blinds on PokerStars
    \item Played over 200,000 hands with 500\$+ profits with rakeback bonus (5bb/100)
    \item Recorded every hand played using HoldemManager and statistically analyzed my unprofitable plays and opponents weaknesses to potentially take advantage of them
    \end{subitems}
  \end{resume_subsection}


\begin{resume_section}{Education}
  \begin{resume_subsection}[Waterloo, ON (2012--Present)]{University of Waterloo}
    \begin{subitems}
      \item Honours Bachelor of Mathematics (Computer Science)
      \item Cummulative Average: 93\%
      \item Honors: Dean's Honours List
    \end{subitems}
  \end{resume_subsection}
  
  
  \begin{resume_subsection}[Westmount, QC (2010--2012)]{Marianopolis College}
    \begin{subitems}
      \item Pure and Applied Science DEC
      \item Cummulative Average: 93\%
     \end{subitems}
  \end{resume_subsection}
\end{resume_section}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I also get this warning: 'hyperref warning: option 'page color' is not available anymore

Answer (score 2):

You forgot a closing `\end{resume_section}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{breaklinks=true,%
  colorlinks=true,%
  linkcolor=cyan,%
  urlcolor=MyDarkBlue}

\definecolor{MyDarkBlue}{rgb}{0,0.0,0.45}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Formatting parameters  %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newlength{\tabin}
\setlength{\tabin}{1em}
\newlength{\secsep}
\setlength{\secsep}{0.1cm}

\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\setlength{\parskip}{0in}
\setlength{\itemsep}{0in}
\setlength{\topsep}{0in}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}

\definecolor{contactgray}{gray}{0.3}
\pagestyle{empty}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%  Template Definitions  %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\lineunder}{\vspace*{-8pt} \\ \hspace*{-6pt} \hrulefill \\ \vspace*{-15pt}}
\newcommand{\name}[1]{\begin{center}\textsc{\Huge#1}\\\end{center}}
\newcommand{\program}[1]{\begin{center}\textsc{#1}\end{center}}
\newcommand{\contact}[1]{\begin{center}\color{contactgray}{\small#1}\end{center}}

\newenvironment{tabbedsection}[1]{
  \begin{list}{}{
      \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
      \setlength{\labelsep}{0pt}
      \setlength{\labelwidth}{0pt}
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\tabin}
      \setlength{\rightmargin}{\tabin}
      \setlength{\listparindent}{0pt}
      \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
      \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
      \setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}
      \setlength{\topsep}{#1}
    }
  \item[]
}{\end{list}}

\newenvironment{nospacetabbing}{
    \begin{tabbing}
}{\end{tabbing}\vspace{-1.2em}}

\newenvironment{resume_header}{}{\vspace{0pt}}


\newenvironment{resume_section}[1]{
  \filbreak
  \vspace{2\secsep}
  \textsc{\large#1}
  \lineunder
  \begin{tabbedsection}{\secsep}
}{\end{tabbedsection}}

\newenvironment{resume_subsection}[2][]{
  \textbf{#2} \hfill {\footnotesize #1} \hspace{2em}
  \begin{tabbedsection}{0.5\secsep}
}{\end{tabbedsection}}

\newenvironment{subitems}{
  \renewcommand{\labelitemi}{-}
  \begin{itemize}
      \setlength{\labelsep}{1em}
}{\end{itemize}}

\newenvironment{resume_employer}[4]{
  \vspace{\secsep}
  \textbf{#1} \\ 
  \indent {\small #2} \hfill {\footnotesize#3 (#4)}
  \begin{tabbedsection}{0pt}
  \begin{subitems}
}{\end{subitems}\end{tabbedsection}}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     Start Document     %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{resume_header}
\name{Joma}
\program{2A Honours Mathematics -- Computer Science Major}
\contact{joma@joma.io \hspace{2cm} 345-234-3245 \hspace{2cm}Student ID: 00000000}
\end{resume_header}

\begin{resume_section}{About Me}
  \begin{nospacetabbing}

  \textbf{Technical Skills}  \= C/C++, Python, Java, Unix/Linux, Excel VBA, MySQL, Scheme, \LaTeX\\*
  \textbf{Languages} \> Fluent in French; Conversational Proficiency in Cantonese\\*
  \textbf{Art Technology} \> Adobe Photoshop, Adobe Premiere Pro, Illustrator\\*
  \textbf{Interests} \> Digital Art, Cinematography, Photography, Design, Poker\\*
  \end{nospacetabbing}

\end{resume_section}

\begin{resume_section}{Work Experience}
  \begin{resume_employer}{Statistics Canada}{Enumerator, Census 2011}{Montreal, QC}{Summer 2011}
    \item Helped and convinced respondents in their dwellings to fill in the census forms
    \item Fixed discrepancies in respondents answers to prevent anomalies in the 2011 Census
    \item Managed and sorted census report in Statistics Canada's online database
  \end{resume_employer}
  
  \begin{resume_employer}{McDonald’s, Aramark Canada, Compass Group}{Cashier, Food Services}{Montreal/Waterloo, QC/ON}{June 2009 - April 2013}
    \item Worked in various food services company as a part time job during studies
    \item Provided excellent customer service while executing quick transactions with accuracy in a stressful and fast paced environment
    \item Maintained a sanitary workplace abiding to Canada's Food and Drugs Act and Regulations
  \end{resume_employer}
\end{resume_section}


\begin{resume_section}{Competitions and Personal Projects}
  \begin{resume_subsection}[(Feburary 2013)]{Rotman International Trading Competition}
  \begin{subitems}
    \item Developed quantitative strategies and applied them during the competition againts undergraduate and graduate students from schools around the world
    \item Implemented Excel VBA macros to facilitate trading and to datamine the simulated cases for research
    \item Wrote a bot for the Algo Case in VBA using their RIT client API that optimizes asset liquidation and profit from arbitrage
    \end{subitems}
  \end{resume_subsection}


  \begin{resume_subsection}[(March 2013)]{Prism Trading Competition}
  \begin{subitems}
    \item Competed in the simulated Sales and Trading Case using the RIT software winning first place (1/12)
    \item Calculated profitability of large offers using VWAP while market making.
    \item Provided liquidity to the market, to profit from competitors large market orders.
    \end{subitems}
  \end{resume_subsection}



  \begin{resume_subsection}[(December 2012)]{Intrade}
    \begin{subitems}
        \item Wrote an algorithm in Python to trade DOW contracts using Black-Scholes binary option pricing.
        \item Automated trades using the Intrade API which required the use of XML processing using ETree libraries
        \item Data mined live feed from various websites for live Index Pricing and Volatility by parsing HTML
    \end{subitems}
  \end{resume_subsection}
  
  \begin{resume_subsection}[(December 2011 - January 2012)]{Poker}
    \begin{subitems}
    \item Simultaneously played 24 cash game tables with 0.01\$/0.02\$ blinds on PokerStars
    \item Played over 200,000 hands with 500\$+ profits with rakeback bonus (5bb/100)
    \item Recorded every hand played using HoldemManager and statistically analyzed my unprofitable plays and opponents weaknesses to potentially take advantage of them
    \end{subitems}
  \end{resume_subsection}
\end{resume_section}% <-----------------------------------------------

\begin{resume_section}{Education}
  \begin{resume_subsection}[Waterloo, ON (2012--Present)]{University of Waterloo}
    \begin{subitems}
      \item Honours Bachelor of Mathematics (Computer Science)
      \item Cummulative Average: 93\%
      \item Honors: Dean's Honours List
    \end{subitems}
  \end{resume_subsection}
  
  
  \begin{resume_subsection}[Westmount, QC (2010--2012)]{Marianopolis College}
    \begin{subitems}
      \item Pure and Applied Science DEC
      \item Cummulative Average: 93\%
     \end{subitems}
  \end{resume_subsection}
\end{resume_section}

\end{document}
```

Also, remove the `pagecolor=white` option from [`hyperref`](//ctan.org/pkg/hyperref).